# What is the best way to remove warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I want to save data in core data. What is the best way to remove this warning?

```
@interface CDPage : NSManagedObject

CDPage *corePage = [CDPage allocWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:manageContext andWithBOPage:page];
[[AppDelegate instance] saveContext];
```

warning: **Unused variable 'corePage'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the variable corePage, you don't need to create it:

```
[CDPage allocWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:manageContext andWithBOPage:page];
[[AppDelegate instance] saveContext];
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign on the same line as you define. Or just don't assign the result of that statement to the variable corePage.